# get xml at regular intervals

Tags: jquery

I'm new on jquery/javascript and I'm trying to trigger a function that get a XML and update fields on my webpage. I've got to call the function and the parsing works, but I'm stalled on execute it every n seconds. I know It's a simple procedure problem. I was coding on assembly a few minutes ago. This is a new planet for me.

This is my code, made with answers from stackoverflow. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.remotehost.com/mw/visor.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){
        var inc=0;
      $(xml).find("bind").each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var tag = $(this).find("tag").text();
        var unidades = $(this).find("units").text();
        var instant = $(this).find("instant").text();

        $("#bind_"+id).text(tag+" "+instant+" "+unidades);
        inc=inc+1;
      })          
    }
   });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(2000, update_data);
});
```

Comment: Idea to hit server every N seconds doesn't sound good!! try something where server can notify you on XML document change

Answer (score 0):

With the second `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` you tell the browser to execute the **function** right after loading is finished.

In your case it starts a timer which runs every `2000 ms` a function called `update_data`. **This function is missing.**

Simply replace the first row `$(document).ready(function(){` with `function update_data(){` and that's it.

The browser will now call the function `update_data` every `2000 ms`.